# How to decompress multiple nested archives of different formats?

Tags: bash, macos, compression, archive

I have hundreds of .zip and .tar archives nested in each other with the unknown depth and I need to decompress all of them to get to the last one, how can I achieve that?
I have the part for the zip files:

```
while 'true' 
do
find . '(' -iname '*.zip' ')' -exec sh -c 'unzip -o -d "${0%.*}" "$0"' '{}' ';'
done
```

but once it stumbles upon the .tar file it expectedly does nothing. I'm running the script on mac.

The structure is just an archive in an archive, the extensions are not in any particular order, like:

```
a.zip/b.zip/c.tar/d.tar/e.zip/f.tar...
```

and so on

Comment: If you have 7zip installed, you can use `7z x` -- that extracts either tar or zip files.

Comment: @Socowi  - I don't think there's 7zip for mac

Comment: Your question doesn't mention the requirement for it to run on Mac. [edit] the question to fix that.

Comment: 7zip is available on mac, it is even in [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/p7zip). +++ If you want an actual answer (with or without 7zip), please show the structure of your archives. Is it just `a.zip/b.tar/c.zip/...` or does one archive contain (nested) directories, other files, or even multiple archives?

Comment: @Socowi added the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an existing command like `7z x` to extract either archive type or build your own using `case "$file" in; *.zip) unzip ...;; *.tar) ...` and so on.

The following script unpacks nested archives as long as the unpacked content is exactly one `.tar` or `.zip` archive. It stops when multiple archives, multiple files, or even directory containing just one `.zip`, were unpacked at once.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# this function can be replaced by `7z x "$1"`
# if 7zip is installed (package managers often call it p7zip)
extract() {
  case "$1" in
    *.zip) unzip "$1" ;;
    *.tar) tar -xf "$1" ;;
    *) echo "Unknown archive type: $1"; exit 1 ;;
  esac
}
isOne() {
  [ $# = 1 ]
}

mkdir out tmp
ln {,out/}yourOutermostArchive.zip # <-- Adapt this line
cd out
shopt -s nullglob
while isOne * && isOne *.{zip,tar}
do
  a=(*)
  mv "$a" ../tmp/
  extract "../tmp/$a"
  rm "../tmp/$a"
done
rm -r ../tmp
cd ..
```